# How can I get current method, class, parent class's folder for all controller in CI before every public method get called?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a rbac in CI 2.1.4. I don't want to use opensource rbac system, because I'm building on an existent system. My resource is designed to: `module_name::controler_name::action_name`, I want to get the `module_name::controler_name::action_name` for the current executed action, eg. `controllers/zoo/suggest.php's index action`. so the module name is `zoo`, controller name is `suggest`, action name is `index`.

But when I'm in this `index` action, how I can get the `zoo`,`suggest`? Yes, it's simple to write some code to get them, but I have hundreds of actions and controllers. I found this way: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372277/how-can-i-create-a-method-that-gets-called-every-time-a-public-method-gets-calle`, but I don't want to write nearly same code in every controller. I just want to write once.

I want to use `post_controller_constructor`, but this hook does not support the acquiring of my would-be-executed method and controller and module name.

How can I succeed my goal?

Comment: CI has a router class try something like `$this->router->class` AND `$this->router->method`

Comment: @sintakonte I know this, but it still need I write code in every action, which sounds horrible.

Comment: do all of you controller have a single parent? I.E CI_Controller?

Comment: @tomexsans Yes! They all extend CI_Controller, and, they all extend Base_Controller which extend CI_Controller

Comment: i don't get it ;) What do you really want ?  is your intention to check whether a user should have access to the specific requested url or is it something else ?